# Sklearn-GMM on large datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bigdata, mixture-model

I have a large data-set (I can't fit entire data on memory). I want to fit a GMM on this data set.

Can I use `GMM.fit()` (`sklearn.mixture.GMM`) repeatedly on mini batch of data ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to fit it repeatedly.
Just randomly sample as many data points as you think your machine can compute in a reasonable time. If variation is not very high, the random sample will have approximately the same distribution as the full dataset.

```
randomly_sampled = np.random.choice(full_dataset, size=10000, replace=False)
#If data does not fit in memory you can find a way to randomly sample when you read it

GMM.fit(randomly_sampled)
```

And the use

```
GMM.predict(full_dataset)
# Again you can fit one by one or batch by batch if you cannot read it in memory
```

on the rest to classify them.

Comment: What if the random sampling still not enough to aproximate the full dataset distribution? Im talking about a mini-batch usually contains between 4-64 samples of datasets of 1,000,000 data samples there is no way a random sample of that size could approximate the distribution well enough.

Answer (score 2):

`fit` will always forget previous data in scikit-learn. For incremental fitting, there is the `partial_fit` function. Unfortunately, `GMM` doesn't have a `partial_fit` (yet), so you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

As Andreas Mueller mentioned, GMM doesn't have `partial_fit` yet which will allow you to train the model in an iterative fashion. But you can make use of `warm_start` by setting it's value to `True` when you create the GMM object. This allows you to iterate over batches of data and continue training the model from where you left it in the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the `init_para` to empty string `''` when you create the `GMM` object, then you might be able to train the whole data set.