# How to solve MemoryError in sklearn when fitting huge data to a GMM?

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, gmm

I am trying to generate a Universal Background Model (UBM) based on a huge array of extracted MFCC features but I keep getting a`MemoryError` when I am fitting my data to the model. Here is the relevant code section:

```
files_features.shape
```

> ```
> (2469082, 56)
> ```

```
gmm = GMM(n_components = 1024, n_iter = 512, covariance_type = 'full', n_init = 3)
gmm.fit(features)
```

Is there a way to solve this error or to decompose the processing of the data to avoid the memory error. I am quite new to this field and would appreciate any help I get.

**[Update]**

Unfortunately the answers mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095769/sklearn-gmm-on-large-datasets) do not solve my issue since the data_set is assumed to have low variance, whereas in my case:

```
round(np.var(files_features), 3)
```

> ```
> 47.781
> ```

Incremental fitting is maybe a solution but `scikit-learn` does not have such a `partial_fit` for GMMs. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to tackle this, whether alternative libs suggestions, partial_fit reference implementations or processing the data batch by batch (which does not work in this case because `GMM.fit()` is memory-less) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sklearn-GMM on large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095769/sklearn-gmm-on-large-datasets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same issue, I recommend the use of the [Bob library](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/stable/bob.bio.gmm/doc/implemented.html), which supports big data processing and even offers parallel processing.

In my use-case [Bob](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/stable/index.html) was a great fit for the development of GMM-UBM systems, as all the relevant functionalities are already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

That's fairly straightforward using [Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).
Just use Dask's DataFrame instead of pandas', and everything else should work without any changes.

As an alternative to scikit-learn, you can use [Turis' Graphlab Create](https://turi.com/), which could handle arbitrary large datasets (though I'm not sure it supports GMM).